# Android change google map marker color without pressing on it

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been trying to change the marker color for a given position on the map,

I've seen many answers online suggesting the usage of ".icon"

Sadly it didn't solve my problem, since the color is now changing only when i press on the marker, not when the location is put on map.

Any idea how to solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new MarkerOptions()
     .position(LatLng)
     .title("text")
     .visible(true)
     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET)));
```

The .defaultMarker() method accepts a float value which is greater than 0 and less and 360. The class includes a few constants such as HUE_VIOLET which I used above.

Answer (score 0):

when you create the marker keep the reference of it as class field like this

```
mStartMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(41.55646,43.56465)
                    .title("Start")
                    .snippet("snippet")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

So when ever you want to change the marker color do it like this

```
mStartMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
```